# How to get Context in onViewCreated

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm attempting to configure a RecyclerView adapter and I have a line of code

```
val decorator = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.decorator)
```

This line of code will not work however as context is nullable and getDrawable requires context. I can think of 4 potential options for getting a non-nullable context in onViewCreated:

1. Wrap the code in `context?.let {}`
2. Wrap the code in `activity?.applicationContext?.let {}`
3. Use `requireContext()`
4. Get context from my application. My application class includes the following code:

```
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApp
            private set

        val context: Context
            get() = instance
    }
```

My dev lead is not a fan of requireContext, and will request that I remove it if he sees it in a pull request. Is he wrong? Help me get Context smart, which of these options are the best and why?

Comment: `view.context` or `requireContext()` (it's safe in `onViewCreated`)

Comment: Yes I considered that option as well, view.context...scary how many ways there are

Comment: Your lead is wrong. `requireContext()` is exactly what you should be using.

Comment: There aren't that many ways, a lot of them are accessing the same ``Context`` object through a particular object they might have access to. But many ways of accessing a context are nullable, because there are situations where you might not have access to it, and then you have to handle that potential null, deferring setup, etc. ``requireContext`` is used when you explicitly *know* you have access to the context, so there's no need to handle the possibility that you don't. If it throws an exception, then that means there's a fundamental logic error in your code you need to fix

Comment: Being afraid of `requireContext()` is a red flag that someone doesn't understand the Fragment lifecycle. Avoiding it is like cargo cult programming. If you can't confidently use `requireContext()` where it's appropriate, you need to read up on the Fragment lifecycle until you can or you're going to have a really hard time properly writing a robust app.